# I can't lead to page 404

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

I am currently working on my new theme, and I have an issue. When I search for something random like "hfdhfsdl", I want it to result in my 404 template, but it only gets header and footer, not the 404 page. My searchform template looks like this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<div>
    <input placeholder="Search for content" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't worked on WP for a while, but I don't think the 404 is triggered for search results being empty. It's only triggered if the page itself doesn't exist. Something like a non existing tag or category url should trigger it.

Comment: @JohnP Read again, I explained the wrong way, sorry!

Comment: It is generally bad practice to show a 404 if there are no results found. Get up your ass and show some site which says : "no results found"!. But if your question is how to display the rest of the site, then you must post the rest of the code!

Answer (score 3):

404 pages are only displayed when a resource isn't found, they're not intended for empty search results, etc..

When you don't get results back, you must display a "No matches found" or something of that sort.